# Why do I always get a security warning everytime I open eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

This didn't used to happen, it started about a week or so ago and it's kind of starting to get on my nerves. Every time I run Eclipse I get one of those windows 7 security warnings asking "Do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher to make changes to your harddrive?" Why has it started asking me this? How do I make it stop? I don't mind getting them in general but this is something I've been using a lot lately and it's only recently started doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I was poking around in the settings and for some reason it was always set to run as administrator. I unchecked that and it stopped.